# but I didn't use /etc/init.d/ in my command!

Tags: command-line, upstart

How can I get this command to work again?

```
$ service tftpd-hpa -start

Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service tftpd-hpa -start

The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but -start is not supported for Upstart jobs.
```

Comment: Why `-start`?  Shouldn't it be just `start` without the dash?  `service tftpd-hpa start`

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for starting Upstart job is `start jobname`. See [Concepts and Terminology](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#concepts-and-terminology) for details.